# Spark RDD take and delete rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of 1000 elements. I want to take 100 elements from it and then remove those 100 from the initial RDD. But I'm not able to find a way for after trying multiple ways.

```
var part = dataRDD.take(100)
```

part is an Array[String]

I want to delete the 100 elements from the 100 of dataRDD.

```
var dataRDD = dataRDD.filter(row => row != part)
```

The above doesn't show any error but doesn't remove any rows. dataRDD still has the same 1000 rows.

Can you please guide on how to get this work.

Comment: Spark's core benefits lie in creating immutable data structures. You shouldn't be using 'var'.

Comment: Yes. But my project is to stream the RDDs in parts. So I had to split and RDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method "zipWithIndex" can be used for split rdd:

```
val zipped = rdd.zipWithIndex()
val first100 = zipped.filter(_._2 < 100).keys
val remaining = zipped.filter(_._2 >= 100).keys
```

Comment: Awesome. This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like:

```
var part = sc.parallelize(dataRDD.take(100))
val result = dataRDD.subtract(part)
result.foreach(x => foreach(x))
```

printing `RDD` for testing purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your code doesn't work as you expect because `row != part` is always `true`. `!=` in this context is a references comparison between arrays from java.